# BDC external contet type SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, external-list, bdc-model, business-data-catalog

I have problem with Business Data Connectivity, when I try to create new external content type in SharePoint Designer - I "Add Connection" then I choose SQL Server I fill Database Server and Name and I can't connect I see "Login failed for user" In Evet Log I have Critical error Event ID 8080.

The BDC service is working and user have perrmision to SQL database.

I use SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Designer.

best regards,
Andrzej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrzej,

SPD2010 may need local admin rights to create this connection, it was the case in my setup anyway. What I did is I have created External Content Type with a logged on user who is a member of local administrators on the SQL server, I haven't had time to get to the bottom of this but it worked. 
I will update this answer as soon as I get this sorted out with only SQL permissions if possible at all.

LW

Comment: Thanks you for your support, I also check it... Best regards